# "Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.Avahi'" how to get rid of this message?

Tags: dbus, avahi

I disabled the `avahi-daemon` according to the method set out [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1339516), namely editing the `/etc/init/avahi-daemon.conf` file to:

```
start on (never
          and filesystem
      and started dbus)
stop on stopping dbus
```

After a reboot, I now get from `service avahi-daemon status` (or `initctl list | grep avahi`)

```
 avahi-daemon stop/waiting
```

Which sounds like I have successfully disabled the service.

However, in my syslog at boot I see :

```
dbus[991]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.Avahi': timed out
dbus[991]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.Avahi': timed out
```

This seems to cost me half a minute of extra boot time...How can I disable this trying to launch `avahi`?

Comment: Depends, does the override method get rid of the dbus message?

Comment: I would start there, if that doesn't work update your question so we can rule it out

Comment: Btw, that method is from 2009. Obviously shouldn't work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> dbus[991]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.Avahi': timed out

This means that it failed to connect to the service since it's not running. The 30 seconds you spend waiting is not because the service is starting, **is because another process expects the service to be running when dbus tries to access the key**. If you want to really stop Avahi you should instead remove the package:

```
sudo apt-get remove avahi-daemon
```

There isn't a sane way to deactivate the daemon without messing with other networking services.